# How to set the browser locale for Selenium tests running in Java?

Tags: java, localization, selenium, integration-testing

I've been [looking](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/java/) [for](http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=selenium.*locale+lang:java&hl=en) a [while](http://www.google.de/search?hl=de&rlz=1C1_____enDE353DE353&q=selenium+locale+java&btnG=Suche&meta=&aq=f&oq=) and still haven't found anything. When I run my Selenium tests from within Eclipse, it opens up a Firefox browser which always has English as its default locale. Changing default browser settings doesn't change the fact that each new browser opened by Selenium has an English locale.

I haven't found any way in the API to set something other than English as my locale. I've tried setting the locale as a VM parameter for the Selenium server, I've tried setting it for my tests.

There's got to be some obvious way of doing this that I'm missing that will result in easy rep for you. :) Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My idea to solve this...

Create Firefox Profiles and open them with Selenium. You can modify them for your needs.

[Selenium Documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#specifying-the-firefox-profile)

By using specific profiles you can avoid this issue. It is not a "nice and clean" Solution..but it works...at least for me.

Comment: I can confirm this is the best solution for now. This sounds like a good feature request, though, so please open an issue!

Answer (score 2):

Now you may use the following snippet for ChromeDriver (in Scala):

```
  private def createDriver(): RemoteWebDriver = {
    val prefs = new util.HashMap[String, Any]()
    prefs.put("intl.accept_languages", "en")

    val options = new ChromeOptions()
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs)

    options.setBinary(chromePath)

    new ChromeDriver(options)
  }
```